# Testing ngrx/effects hitting success action in fail test

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm trying to test the fail action in my effect, and I modeled it after [Brian Love's](https://brianflove.com/2018/06/28/ngrx-testing-effects/) blog. However, when I'm testing fail, I receive an error message saying it was expecting a success action.

Here's my code:

search.service.ts:

```
    save(acronym: Acronym) {
    if (acronym.id) {
        return this.update(acronym);
    } else {
        return this.add(acronym);
    }
}

add(acronym: Acronym) {
    return this.db.collection(config.acronyms).add(acronym).then(() => this.search(acronym.code, acronym.project));
}

update(acronym: Acronym) {
    return this.db.collection(config.acronyms).doc(acronym.id).update(acronym).then(() => this.search(acronym.code, acronym.project));
}
```

effect.ts

```
    @Effect()
saveAcronym$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(acronymActions.SAVE_ACRONYM),
    map((action: acronymActions.SaveAcronym) => action.payload),
    mergeMap((payload) => {
        this._searchService.save(payload);
        return of(payload);
    }),
    map(data => new acronymActions.SaveAcronymSuccess(data)),
    catchError(error => of(new acronymActions.SaveAcronymFail(error)))
);
```

effect.spec.ts

```
        it("should return a SaveAcronymFail action, with an error, on fail", () => {
        const payload = {code: "SME", project: "SWAN"};
        const action = new fromActions.SaveAcronym(payload);
        const error = new Error();
        const result = new fromActions.SaveAcronymFail(error);

        actions = hot("-a", {a: action});
        const response = cold("-#|", {}, error);
        const expected = cold("--(b|)", {b: result});

        searchService.save = jest.fn(() => response);

        expect(effects.saveAcronym$).toBeObservable(expected);
    });
```

action.ts

```
export class SaveAcronymFail implements Action {
readonly type = SAVE_ACRONYM_FAIL;

constructor(public payload: Error) {}
```

}

reducer.ts:

```
        case AcronymActions.SAVE_ACRONYM_FAIL:
        return {...state, loading: false, loaded: true};
```

And the error:

```
    expect(received).toEqual(expected)

Expected value to equal:
  [{"frame": 20, "notification": {"error": undefined, "hasValue": true, "kind": "N", "value": {"payload": [Error], "type": "[ACRONYM] Save Fail"}}}, {"frame": 20, "notification": {"error": undefined, "hasValue": false, "kind": "C", "value": undefined}}]
Received:
  [{"frame": 10, "notification": {"error": undefined, "hasValue": true, "kind": "N", "value": {"payload": {"code": "SME", "project": "SWAN"}, "type": "[ACRONYM] Save Success"}}}]
```

I tried modifying the frames, but with no luck.

Answer (score -2):

try this code **effect.spec.ts**

```
it('should return an fail action, with an error, on failure', () => {
  const user = generateUser();
  const action = new AddData({ user });
  const error = new Error();
  const outcome = new AddDatafail({ error });
  actions = hot('-a|', { a: action });
  const response = cold('-#|', {}, error);
  const expected = cold('--(b|)', { b: outcome });
  serService.saveSampleData = jest.fn(() => response);
  expect(effects.AddData).toBeObservable(expected););
});
```

Comment: Please format your code, this is completely unreadable! Besides you could add some explanation why the OP should use your code and how it solves the issue.